# Find specific word inside a string in xml tag using regex in notepad++?

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

`<name>`My name is Tom but people call me as XYZ but my actual name is Tommy!`</name`>

- Now, I want to find "Tom" inside the specified xml tag, and replace it with Harry.
- Finding, multiple instances of "Tom" and replace it with "Harry" from the string inside the specified XML tag.

**Example:**
`(?<=<name>)[a-zA-Z]*(Tom)[a-zA-Z]*(?=<\/name>)`,

- This is not able to find the word "Tom" from the specified string between XML tag.

Comment: Can `<name>` tag contain other tags?

Comment: No, it contains only <name></name> tags. There are so many tags in my XML file, but I'm targeting only <name> tags. And <name> does not contain any other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `name` tag cannot have any other tags inside, the regex that can solve the issue is

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<name>)[^<]*?\K\bTom\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ktl03s/1). Replace with `Harry`.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<name>)` - the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the `<name>` substring
- `[^<]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `<`, as few as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\bTom\b` - whole word `Tom` (remove `\b` word boundaries if you need to match `Tom` in `Tommy`).

NOTE: If you also want to match `Tommy`, replace `\bTom\b` with `\bTom(?:my)?\b`.

Answer (score 1):

Find what : `(?<=<name>)(.*?)(Tom)(?=\b.*</name>)`
Replace with : `$1Harry`

Detail :
Balise name : `(?<=<name>)`
Anything between name and Tom`(.*?)`
Tom `(Tom)`
A boudary to check the end of the word Tom`(?=\b`
Anything between tom and the closing name balise `.*`
The closing balise `</name>)`

Reinject what's between the balise name and tom`$1`
Replacing Tom by Harry`Harry`